# Not able to route to partial view in MEAN app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, pug, mean-stack

I'm doing a tutorial for building single page apps with the MEAN stack. I've been successful with rendering to the index.jade view. However, when I try to list a route to a partial view, the DOM of the page doesn't render the view. Maybe this will be clear with the code

server.js

```
var express = require("express");
var stylus = require("stylus");
var logger = require("morgan");
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');


var env = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV || "development";

var app = express();

function compile(str, path) {                       
    return stylus(str).set('filename', path);       
}

app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');  

app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser());

app.use(stylus.middleware ({
    src: __dirname + "/public",
    compile: compile
}
));
app.use(express.static(__dirname, 'public'));   

app.get('/partials/:partialPath', function (req, res) {
    res.render('partials/'+ req.params.partialPath);
})



app.get('*', function (req, res) {    
    res.render('index');                
});                             


var port = 3030;
app.listen(port);
console.log("Listening on port number " + port);
```

layout.jade

```
doctype

html
    head
        link(href="/favicon.ico", rel="shortcut icon", type="image/x-icon")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/bootstrap.css")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="/vendor/toastr/toastr.css")
        link(rel="stylesheet", href="/css/site.css")

    body(ng-app='app')
        h1 Layout
        block content
    include scripts
```

index.jade

```
extends ../includes/layout

block content

    section.content
        div(ng-view)
        h2 index.jade
```

app.js

```
angular.module("app", ["ngResource", "ngRoute"]); 

angular.module('app').config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/partials/main',
            controller: 'mainCtrl'
        })
});

angular.module('app').controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.myVar = "Hello Anglularz";
});
```

main.jade

```
extends ../../includes/layout

block content

    section.partial
    h1 This is a partial
    h2 {{ myVar }}
```

Have no idea what is going wrong. I suspect the problem is with the routing. 
Also, if possible, please explain how the templateUrl and app.get routing works together.

Answer (score 0):

```
---write routes for partials also in express

---call that routes inside angular controller and bind that values into scope variables

---use ng-include="" in DOM and call that partial views
```

In the case of templateUrl also express routes will work directly